# Cannot find Prof. Sycamore in Lumiose Station after defeating The Elite Four

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have visited the Lab and Lumiose Station in search for the Professor and still cannot find him.

Where is he? Where (or how) can I find him?

Comment: Are you sure he's not at the station? That's the only place he can be at right after beating the Elite Four.

Answer (score 2):

You have to beat the Champion to get to Kiloude City. After beating the Champion and seeing the credits, you will get a message from Professor Sycamore, telling you to meet him in Lumiose City Train station.

The train station is located on the Northern Boulevard of Lumiose City. Inside it looks like this:
[image: Lumiose City Train Station]

As you can see from the picture, Professor Sycamore will be waiting just past the entrance. Interact with him and he will give you a train ticket to go to Kiloude.

If you have already claimed the ticket, you can interact with that Orange Box next to him to scan the ticket and board the train.

#### References

- [Lumiose City - IGN](http://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-x-y/Lumiose_City_-_North_Boulevard)
- [Lumiose Train Station - Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lumiose_City#Lumiose_Station)